# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus.NONE

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hbase

```
~$ hive
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hbase-2.0.6/lib/phoenix-5.0.0-HBase-2.0-client.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hbase-2.0.6/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop-3.1.1/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
2019-12-18 09:46:56,992 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hbase-2.0.6/lib/phoenix-5.0.0-HBase-2.0-client.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/apache-hive-3.1.1-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop-3.1.1/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2019-12-18 09:46:58,147 INFO  [main] conf.HiveConf: Found configuration file file:/usr/local/apache-hive-3.1.1-bin/conf/hive-site.xml
2019-12-18 09:46:58,730 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Hive Session ID = f9e3143f-b573-4c36-a7d3-c9a25ff11faa
2019-12-18 09:47:00,277 INFO  [main] SessionState: Hive Session ID = f9e3143f-b573-4c36-a7d3-c9a25ff11faa

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/apache-hive-3.1.1-bin/lib/hive-common-3.1.1.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
2019-12-18 09:47:00,320 INFO  [main] SessionState: 
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/apache-hive-3.1.1-bin/lib/hive-common-3.1.1.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus.NONE from class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.HdfsFileStatus
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.HdfsFileStatus.convert(HdfsFileStatus.java:520)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.HdfsLocatedFileStatus.<init>(HdfsLocatedFileStatus.java:87)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.HdfsFileStatus$Builder.build(HdfsFileStatus.java:282)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelperClient.convert(PBHelperClient.java:1762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:901)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:1654)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$29.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1579)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$29.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1576)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1668)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.ensurePathIsWritable(Utilities.java:4486)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:757)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:624)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:588)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:747)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:683)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:239)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I'm seeing it too.

Comment: @Christopher, I observed in Hortonworks Sandbox, it is not possible to activate hive and hbase  at the same time. So you can activate only one of the two at a time. Not both. So it is expected  it works fine.

Comment: I actually think this might be a dependency convergence issue. I don't know anything about Hortonworks Sandbox, Hive, or HBase, but I saw the same exception when I had a dependency mismatch with some commons-* jars and/or guava mismatch on my class path between my application and the HDFS client. I don't know the details of the issue, but I suspect it would work better if all the software were compiled in a dependency-converged environment.